# How to delete a bracket in the attribute table of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I would like to delete a bracket (`[]`) in one column of my attribute table. I have different numbers in the column, written like this "[901], [555]..." How can I delete the bracket, withouth having to edit each field?

I am using QGIS version 2.12.3-Lyon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete all brackets in the column you go for:

`replace("your_column",'[','')`

It searches for all the brackets and replaces them by nothing.

If it needs to be a special position where the brackets are you need to find them:

For example by position with left, right or substr functions when the position is always the same in each line.

If not you need to find the position dynamicly with strpos or you use regular expressions with regexp_replace.

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what I needed!! thanks a lot